# Dataweave2.0 in mule 4

Tags: mule, dataweave

```
   notes=(payload.examples if payload.examples != null else “ “) ++ (\n\n**column1:\ntest: “ ++ vars.name) ++ ( “\n column2: “ ++ vars.date) ++ (“\n column3: “ ++ attributes.headers.speech)
```

This is DataWeave 2.0 but error said invalid input. Anyone knows how to fix this in mule 4?

Comment: This is not a complete script. Please add: complete DataWeave script, input example (payload, variables, attribute.headers.speech), complete error message (to understand what failed), and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comment code of DataWeave 1.0. Please find the below corresponding DataWeave 2.o code.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json  
---
{
(payload mapObject (value, key) -> {
((key): value) if (key as String != "notes")
}),
notes: 
if (payload.examples != null)
  payload.examples
else
  "" ++ ("\n\n**column1:\ntest: " ++ vars.name) ++ ("\n column2: " ++ vars.date) ++      ("\n column3: " ++ attributes.headers.speech)
```

}

Answer (score 2):

the part where you are performing the condition check with if, the '=!' should be '!='.Please let me know if this has helped you.

Comment: Hello. Sorry for the mistake. I did put it as !=.

Comment: Ok. Can you provide a sample input and the expected output in the question?

Comment: Hi this code is actually from mule 3. It works in mule 3 but the expression change in mule 4 so I’m trying to update it according to mule 4 standard ‘% dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
   (payload mapObject (value,key) -> {
       ((key):value) when (key as :string != “notes”)
    }),
    notes: (( payload.examples when payload.examples != null otherwise " ")
    ++ ("\n\n**column1:\ntest: " ++ flowVars.name)
    ++("\ncolumn2: " ++ flowVars.date)
    ++("\ncolumn3: " ++ inboundProperties.speech)
}